# Why my ggplot lines look broken

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to smooth my density line? The lines very jiggly with look broken.

```
x = rnorm(1000);

    # overlay histogram, empirical density and normal density
    p0 = qplot(x, geom = 'blank') +   
      geom_line(aes(y = ..density.., colour = 'Empirical'), stat = 'density') +  
      stat_function(fun = dnorm, aes(colour = 'Normal')) +                       
      geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), alpha = 0.4) +                        
      scale_colour_manual(name = 'Density', values = c('red', 'blue')) + 
      theme(legend.position = c(0.85, 0.85))

    print(p0)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to improve jagged line graph in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323294/how-to-improve-jagged-line-graph-in-ggplot2)

Comment: The problem is that you are using `stat = density`, which is not the same as fitting a normal distribution to the histogram. density plots use the `density` function, which applies a smoothing kernel over a bandwidth. `https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/density.html`